# File Upload Issue

Tags: media

I uploaded a image file after creating a new content type. But the uploaded image is not being displayed only the name of the image is being displayed. I need to click on the name to view the image, kindly tell how can I make the image to be displayed in the page itself without having to click on the image to view it.

Answer (score 0):

what I assume file is getting uploaded as you are able to see the file once clicking on the link,if so please change the title.

Regarding problem,I assume you are not using views or any other module to show the nodes,so how a field renders pretty much depends on what manage dsiplay option has been opted for it, you can check the selected manage diaply by visiting "admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type_name/display" and then selecting the image format display for the field.